# Google Blogger API removeContent returns 403 for blog administrator

Tags: python, blogger, google-oauth

Trying to use Google API for Blogger
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/comments/removeContent

The results of my testing of the `removeContent` method is that it only works when I'm using OAuth token for the comment author.

When I'm using the OAuth token for the blog administrator I get 403.
But other write operations such as `delete` and `markAsSpam` works fine when using the blog administrator's OAuth token.

In summary, why does `removeContent` not work as blog administrator?